# How to press Enter Key within Text box in Power shell?

Tags: powershell

I am interacting with Web page using Power shell script, Once i logged into the page i need to provide a value to the Text box, after its done, i need to press enter within that text box to start search.

```
$ie.document.getElementById("textbox-Input-ffd1").value = $value
```

can you please help how i can achieve that using power shell?
I have tried below script already and it doesn't work as expected, i need it to be specific within text box.

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{Enter}")
```

Comment: This is not working within the textbox content provided, its just passing enter on the Webpage.

Comment: Sorry, San_thi. It was worth a shot. Nevertheless, it *does* press the enter key. So now, you just need script to select the right UI item as the focus. Do you have an example web page I can experiment on to hopefully get you an answer that works?